# What kind of entries Feedjira has?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, feedzirra, feedjira

I started to use feedjira. I'm getting entries from url:

```
feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(self.url)

puts "Fetching from #{self.url}"

feed.entries.each do |entry|
  unless Feed.exists? guid: entry.id
    newFeed = Feed.create(name: entry.title,
                          summary: entry.summary,
                          url: entry.url,
                          published_at: entry.published,
                          guid: entry.id)

    self.feeds << newFeed
  end
end
```

I found these entries from tutorials. I haven't found entries from documentation. Are there any other entries that I can get from url like categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source of feedjira](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/blob/master/lib/feedjira/parser/rss_entry.rb), category is defined as categories for RSS feed.

> `elements :category, :as => :categories`

The type of available elements depends on the source of the feed. (Atom/iTunes/FeedBurner)

So you can use `author`, `content`, `updated`, and `image` for RSS feed.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Does categories have some kind of standartized names or each site will write categories differently?

Comment: @Mr.D I'am afraid it is not the same. Keep in mind that [RSS spec](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification) only treated category as optional element. Even if RSS publisher provided the category information, it may be tags instead.

Comment: It throws me `NoMethodError: undefined method `categories' for #<Feedjira::Parser::ITunesRSSItem:0x000000094237c8>` error. But rss items in xml has category

Comment: @Mr.D Possible reason is that the feed is misclassified as ITunesRSSItem. You can try [patching the code by comment out the ITunesRSSItem line](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/issues/176#issuecomment-29171760)

Comment: @Mr.D Just paste the code in your ruby file to override the default setting. Less recommended way is to modify the original library. Path is feedjira/lib/feedjira/feed.rb